# MESFET in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, fet

It is really confusing to me. For some reasons I am  migrating from Microcap SPICE3 to LTSpice. While in Microcap there was no issue with Statz model for GaAs MESFET, I cant figure out how to incorporate Statz model into LTSpice.[image]

I tried almost every possible combination, but not the right one yet :)
According to LTWiki, LTSpice is also capable of simulations with Statz model of MESFET, see [link](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Z_MESFET_transistor).

What am I missing here? Can you suggest me step-by-step reference applied specifically for Z type devices?

**Edit:** SPICE3 model in Microcap is given by

.MODEL T1 GASFET (LEVEL=1 AF=1 ALPHA=2 B=300m BETA=0.08 BETATCE=0 CDS=0.15P

- CGD=0.05P CGS=0.3P DELTA=0.2 EG=1.11 FC=500m GAMMA=0 IS=10f KF=0 LAMBDA=0 M=500m
- N=1 Q=2 RD=0.62 RG=0.98 RS=1.38 TAU=7P TRD1=0 TRG1=0 TRS1=0 VBI=1 VDELTA=200m
- VMAX=500m VTO=-1 VTOTC=0 XTI=0)

Comment: Can you spot the difference: `.model nmf nmf beta=...`? ;-) Some parameters may not be recognized and they will be ignored (at the cost of a minor nag from the error log).

Comment: Oh god..... this helped a lot, now I am having same results. Now I need to figure out, how to accept your answer. Can you post some short comment as answear please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the model name, or the type; difficult to say if you're using the default `NMF` name:

```
.model n nmf beta=80m vto=-1
+ cds=150f cgd=50f cgs=300f
+ rd=0.62 rg=0.98 rs=1.38
```

With this change (above), some help for an oscillator circuit (supply starting from zero), and a minor tweak (precharged output cap) the schematic will run:

[image: mesfet]

Not all parameters will be recognized so they will be ignored. If you want to avoid pop-ups from the error log (see picture), simply delete them.